# Docusign api document has a password property

Tags: docusignapi

I see the password property on a Document. Does this somehow tie in with the Advanced options in Docusign's UI for making templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the source code of Java SDK and it is really there, but there is no docs about it.

```
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "")
  @JsonProperty("password")
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
```

My guess is it's there for compatibility purposes and is deprecated. All other properties have the proper documentation.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense that it's deprecated. Thank you.